# Unwanted extra frame during stacked sprite render

Tags: editor, render, godot, sprite-sheet, godot4

I built a stacked sprite using the Sprite2D node made of 9 slices of a car. When I rotate the sprite, there is one extra default layer that remains unrotated and sticks out like a sore thumb.

[image: Sprite Render with extra un-rotating layer of shadow]

My code for rotating the stacked sprite is rather simple and works as expected. However, I am uncertain why an extra layer is rendering of my sprite. I am able to manipulate the layer that is shown via setting the default 'frame' in the Godot editor but would rather this additional frame be entirely removed. I have considered adding a 10th layer of pure transparency and setting this as the default (which certainly would fix the problem aesthetically). However, I would much prefer a more concrete solution to this problem going forward.